# Не работает .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Не работает переадресация всех запросов на index.php и выдает ошибку, как я понял, то проблема в том, что апач не учитывает настройки моего файла .htaccess.

Вот настройки апача из файла настройек httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "c:/Server/bin/Apache24"

Listen 80

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User daemon
    Group daemon 
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot "c:/Server/data/htdocs/"


<Directory />
    Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/Server/data/htdocs/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.shtml index.php
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
    Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

PHPIniDir "C:/Server/bin/PHP"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Server/bin/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

Вот ссылка на [полный конфиг](https://ideone.com/DmPQ2v)

Вот содержимое htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, содержимое htaccess и опишите, какая ошибка возникает.

Comment: Ошибка возникает, не найден урл, предположим открывается главная, я нажимаю на кнопку на сайте и в этой кнопке хранится экшен который должен открыть нужный урл, этот урл должен переадресоваться на индекс пхп и быть обработан, но вместо этого не переадресовывается и просто выдает ошибку "не найден урл", так как действительно файла с таким адресом нет, но если бы он был обработан контроллером, то открылсь бы то, что мне нужно.

Comment: AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

Comment: Визуально всё выглядит верно. `AllowOverride all` в хосте присутствует, модуль загружается, htaccess верен. Попробуйте посмотреть логи сервера, может будет за что зацепиться.

Comment: @lupti_du риложите к вопросу фрагмент кода с кнопкой. Не лишним будет указать какой фреймворк используете.

Comment: Простите за банальные вопросы. Но уточните вы уверены, что htaccess вообще обрабатывается, пробовали специально сделать ошибку в файле чтобы получить 500-й отклик? Возможно у вас также работает nginx и перехватывает запросы.

Answer (score 2):

Первым делом нужно проверить обрабатывается ли htaccess. Для этого нужно сохранить его с любым текстом не имеющим смысла. Если получите 500-ю ошибку, то файл обрабатывается.

Далее нужно проверить заголовки сервера, например с помощью https://bertal.ru/ или инструментов разработчика Google Chrome - вкладка Network. Вполне возможно (на хостингах), что в заголовках ответа в качестве сервера вы увидите не Apache, а nginx. Тогда нужно смотреть как настроен nginx. Как правило он может искать запрашиваемые ссылки физически в файловой системе.

Answer (score 2):

В вашей настройке не указано как будет называться AccessFile, нужно добавить "AccessFileName .htaccess" в конфиге apache.

Answer (score 0):

А так?

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: все равно не работает

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже была такая проблема. Но я решил. Нашёл два способа:

1. Это решается со стороны хоcтинга. Если они не хотят или не могут, то нужно менять хостинг.
2. Перед названием контроллера добавить `index.php`.
   Например:

   ```php
   base_url().'index.php/controller_name/function_name';
   ```

   Ещё, на всякий случай вот тут содержимое моего файла .htaccess:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteBase /siteroot/
```